# Wamp + Certificado SSL

Tags: ssl, wamp

Eu consegui realizar a instalação do certificado Openssl no Wamp. Mas eu tenho uma pergunta e se você pode me ajudar, eu ficarei grato:
Ao instalar, no navegador apareceu uma navegação segura
(Cadeado verde). Por enquanto, tudo bem. Ao tentar acessar a máquina que instalei o certificado através de outra maquina, ou de um smartphone através do IP da maquina, a resposta no smartphone e na outra máquina foi de navegação não segura, ou seja, fora da maquina que foi instalado o certificado não é reconhecido.
É possível resolver esse erro? É a configuração do certificado, no Wamp ou possivelmente na rede?

Comment: Você comprou um certificado de uma certificadora como a CertSign, ou gerou um certificado auto-assinado ?

Comment: Provavelmente o problema está relacionado ao domínio associado ao certificado, caso o certificado seja _auto-assinado_. Veja neste link (em inglês): https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-faqs/ssl-certificate-errors.html

Comment: AnthraxisBR eu gerei um certificado auto-assinado, da Openssl, eu ainda não comprei não. Como estou aprendendo desenvolvimento web realizei um teste com esse grátis

Comment: E´auto-assinado sim David Samm, vou dar uma olhada. Obrigado